# how to get extension of file,if i have only name and path of this file

Tags: java, io

I tried ApacheCommons IO,but there looking for ".[extension]" for checking,but i have only

```
/resourse/image1
```

So how to get extension?At all it is possible?

Comment: How do you know if that path points to `image1.jpg` or `image1.png`? Where are you getting that path anyway?

Comment: You won’t be able to find the file without the extension. Even if there is only one file (image.whatever), reading that in will not find it/throw FileNotFoundException etc.

Comment: its resource path,that contains,for example `image.png` ,and i have to parce all files with name `image1`, but dont know how

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to:

- Take your path string and split it at the last (!!) slash `/` character.
- the left part of this split is a folder path. Iterate over all files in that folder.
- filter the list of files to include only those where the file name starts with the right part of your split followed by a dot character.

The files which pass this filter are your potential match candidates. If you are lucky then there is only one. Otherwise you cannot decide and e.g. need to ask the user.